# Where is the __sysctl function defined in FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, sysctl, source-code

I am reading the source code to understand `sysctl` in FreeBSD.

It looks like the most important function

```
int __sysctl(const int *name, u_int namelen, void *oldp, size_t *oldlenp, const void *newp, size_t newlen);
```

is not defined in `lib/libc/gen/sysctl.c`.

I tried to grep over FreeBSD's source code but I failed to find the defintion of `__sysctl`.

Where is it defined?

Comment: libc's `__sysctl` is a system call wrapper written in a few lines of assembly language, generated during the compilation of libc. Did you want to see that source, or the source in the kernel that handles that system call?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I want to understand how `sysctl` works. I couldn't find any in-depth explanation online so I decided to read the source code.

Comment: `/usr/src/sys/kern/kern_sysctl.c` or https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/sys/kern/kern_sysctl.c?view=markup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I've learnt:

- `__syscall` is not defined in any C source file;

  According to Mark Plotnick:

  > `libc`'s `__sysctl` is a system call wrapper written in a few lines of assembly language, generated during the compilation of `libc` [[1](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/sys/kern/syscalls.master?revision=302525&view=markup)].
- The system calls' entry point is [here in kern_sysctl.c](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/sys/kern/kern_sysctl.c?view=markup#l1894) [[2](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/sys/kern/kern_sysctl.c?view=markup#l1894)]. The system calls are called `sys_foo()` in the kernel.

#### Links

1. [Configuration file for generating syscalls.](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/sys/kern/syscalls.master?revision=302525&view=markup)
2. [The kern_sysctl.c source.](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/sys/kern/kern_sysctl.c?view=markup#l1894)

Thanks to edje, Ed Schouten (@EdSchouten), @FreeBSDHelp and Mark Plotnick.